# Loading folder content

Tags: javascript

Is there any possible way to read some certain folder's content using javascript?
for example: 
I have a folder with some file.txt, and I'd like to automatically list all the item in html.
[image]

I want the HTML automatically list it all like:

```
    <ul id="folder1">
      <li>1.txt</li>
      <li>2.txt</li>
      <li>3.txt</li>
      <li>4.txt</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: place that in a file server, then access it thru link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure JavaScript code running in browser can't access the local file system, so you should running JavaScript in NodeJS and output filesystem structure as a pure html.

here is the example code:

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

// create the server object
http.createServer(function(req, resp) {
    files = fs.readdirSync(".");

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var line = "<div><a href='#'>"+ files[i] +"</a></div>";
        resp.write(line);
    }

    resp.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Save this code as app.js and run it using: node app.js, then open browser to http://localhost:8080, you will see the local filesystem in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, just use an [`<input type="file" directory multiple>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file), but make sure to use all [`directory` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-webkitdirectory) with vendor prefixes `webkit`, `moz`, `ms`, and `o` to account for all implementations, since [this is technically a non-standard feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/webkitRelativePath):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const ul = document.querySelector('ul')

input.addEventListener('change', function () {
  while (ul.children.length > 0) {
    ul.firstElementChild.remove()
  }
  
  for (const file of this.files) {
    const li = document.createElement('li')

    // fallback if non-standard property does not exist
    li.textContent = file.webkitRelativePath || file.name
    ul.append(li)
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple/>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Through straight Javascript executed in a browser, no. What you would have to do is make the folder accessible on the server then use JS code to read it as an AJAX call or something similar.

If you're using command line JS (like Node.js or something similar), you can access the file system and read a file. Node.js uses the `fs` package.